# How can I get the list of required parameters of a yii 2.0 action as an array?

Tags: php, yii2

When a user visits a particular url in my yii 2.0 application without required parameters, I want to present a form to collect the required missing parameters.

for this purpose, I need the names of missing parameters, e.g. I have a function

```
 public function actionBlast ($bomb, $building) {

  }
```

I expect the results as an array like this

```
$args = [0=>'bomb', 1=>'building'];
```

I tried `func_get_args()` but it returns null, and the undocumented `ReflectionFunctionAbstract::getParameters ( void )` etc.  Any other way out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to achieve what you want is to override the default ErrorAction. 
Inside your controllers directory, create:

- controllers

  - actions

    - ErrorAction.php

In ErrorAction.php, add:

```
<?php

namespace frontend\controllers\actions;

use Yii;
use yii\web\ErrorAction as DefaultErrorAction;

class ErrorAction extends DefaultErrorAction
{
    public function run()
    {
        $missing_msg = 'Missing required parameters:';
        $exception = Yii::$app->getErrorHandler()->exception;
        if (substr($exception->getMessage(), 0, strlen($missing_msg)) === $missing_msg) {

            $parameters = explode(',', substr($exception->getMessage(), strlen($missing_msg)));
            return $this->controller->render('missing_params_form' ?: $this->id, [
                'parameters' => $parameters,
            ]);
        }
        return parent::run();
    }
}
```

In your controller add:

```
public function actions()
{
    return [
        'error' => [
            'class' => 'frontend\controllers\actions\ErrorAction',
        ],
    ];
}
```

and create a view "missing_params_form.php" in your controller `s view directory, where you can generate your form fields.

I believe this to be your best option, though you may need to update it in case a Yii update changes the error message.

Comment: `$parameters = explode(',', substr($exception->getMessage(), strlen($missing_msg)));` This thing is not very beautiful, instead we should  focus on how Yii2 is collecting the missing parameters. But your suggestion to use override ErrorAction is a really good idea and deserves a vote.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not think there is a pretty way to do this. You can have a look at "bindActionParams()" of yii\web\Controller and use the code that is there.

Comment: meanwhile, don't you the think the question deserves a vote =D